# Kubuntu 16.04 Double Background Issue

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments, bug-reporting, desktop-background

When I log in via the Plasma desktop environment (DE), I cannot access the desktop, but can access files via Dolphin. I think this is caused by a corruption of my install of Plasma, GNOME, and Ubuntu DE's.

[Here is a screenshot of my desktop when I log in via Plasma.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ittRm.png)

Comment: Okay, so running Kubuntu with the Ubuntu DE disables pretty much everything except for the desktop and I can access the terminal.  Currently, I'm in GNOME and it seems to be running fine.  I want to say that the best thing I can do is to uninstall and reinstall KDE.

Comment: Is there a command I can input to find out which files are missing?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I had some trouble with that. Lemme revisit the issue later today or tomorrow and I'll see if I can describe why that was an issue as well.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Pardon me for the delay.  Thank you for showing interest.